# Issue in react component

Tags: reactjs

I have a problem in the following component, it seems that the component doesn't render and I get the following error in console: "Cannot read property 'operationalHours' of null". I don't get why operationalHours it's null.. maybe someone can help me with a posible solution for this issue.
Here is the component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Search from 'client/components/ui/Search';
import { performSearchById } from 'client/actions/api/search';
import { get } from 'lodash';
import {
  SEARCH_STORE_NOT_CLOSED,
  SEARCH_STORE_OPEN_TEXT,
  SEARCH_STORE_CLOSED_TEXT
} from 'app/client/constants/values';

import DownArrow from 'components/UI/icons/DownArrow';

import styles from './styles.module.scss';

const StoreDetails = ({ storeInfo }) => {
  const [expanded, setIsExpanded] = useState(false);
  const [storeData, setStoreData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const storeId = storeInfo.store_id;
      const {
        data: {
          Location: {
            contactDetails: { phone },
            operationalHours
          }
        }
      } = await performSearchById(storeId);
      setStoreData({ phone, operationalHours });
    }
    fetchData();
  }, [storeInfo.store_id]);

  const infoText = expanded ? 'Hide details' : 'View details';

  function parseHours(hours) {
    const formattedHours = {};
    hours.forEach(dayObj => {
      const closed = get(dayObj, 'closed', '');
      const day = get(dayObj, 'day', '');
      if (closed === SEARCH_STORE_NOT_CLOSED) {
        const openTime = get(dayObj, 'openTime', '');
        const closeTime = get(dayObj, 'closeTime', '');
        if (openTime === null || closeTime === null) {
          formattedHours[day] = SEARCH_STORE_OPEN_TEXT;
        } else {
          formattedHours[day] = `${openTime}-${closeTime}`;
        }
      } else {
        formattedHours[day] = SEARCH_STORE_CLOSED_TEXT;
      }
    });
    return formattedHours;
  }

  const storeHours = storeData.operationalHours
    ? parseStoreHours(storeData.operationalHours)
    : '';

  return (
    <div className={styles.viewStoreDetails}>
      <span
        className={expanded ? styles.expanded : undefined}
        onClick={() => setIsExpanded(!expanded)}
      >
        <DownArrow />
      </span>
      <div>
        <span className={styles.viewStoreDetailsLabel}>{infoText}</span>
        <div>
          {expanded && (
            <Search
              phoneNumber={storeData.phone}
              storeHours={storeHours}
            />
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default StoreDetails;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you're setting the values of `storeData` after the component has already rendered the first time. Your default value for `storeData` is `null`.

It breaks here: `storeData.operationalHours` because `null` isn't an object and therefore cannot have properties to access on it.

You should probably just set your initial state to something more representative of your actual state:

```js
const [storeData, setStoreData] = useState({}); // Or even add keys to the object.
```

Also read [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) about the `useEffect` hook and when it runs. It seems that the underlying issue is misunderstanding when your data will be populated.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting error at this line :

```
    const storeHours = storeData.operationalHours ? 
                 parseStoreHours(storeData.operationalHours): '';
```

Reason : You initialised **storeData** as Null and you are trying to access **operationalHours** key from Null value.

Correct Way is :

Option 1: Initialise  storeData as blank object

```
  const [storeData, setStoreData] = useState({});
```

Option 2:

```
  const storeHours =storeData && storeData.operationalHours ? 
                 parseStoreHours(storeData.operationalHours): '';
```

Answer (score 0):

It's happen because in 1st moment of your application, `storeData` is `null`, and `null` don't have properties, try add a empty object as first value (`{}`) or access a value like that:

**Correct method:**

```
const object = null;
console.log(object?.myProperty);

// output: undefined
```

**Wrong method:**

```
const object = null;
console.log(object.myProperty);

// Generate a error
```

The **Question Mark**(`?`) is a method to hidden or ignore if the variable are a non-object, to decrease verbosity in the code with logic blocks `try` and `catch`, in **Correct method** code there will be no mistake, but in **Wrong method** code, there will have a mistake.

**Edit 1**:

See more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)